# How to implement multiple columns table with jquery mobile?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am new to jquery mobile. Now I want to implement table with multiple columns for tablet UI. How can I implement this multiple columns table concept by using jquery mobile framework. Please guide me if any one did this concept.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding something like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
<div class="ui-block-a">Block A</div>
<div class="ui-block-b">Block B</div>
<div class="ui-block-c">Block C</div>
```

This is a grid layout. There is not something like table in JQM, but it may imitate it.

Try this link: [jQM Grids](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/content/content-grids.html)

Comment: The above code only works for up to 5 colomns but i need to display morethan 8 colomns. Is any other alternative for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try out the popular plugin - 960 Grid http://jeromeetienne.github.com/jquery-mobile-960/

It allows for a lot more flexibility in the way you arrange your grids with flexible widths, etc.

By the way, I am not advertising :)

Comment: You are right. But this plugin should be used carefully. It may not look good on small screens.